# Symbolic link with Vagrant and CentOS 7

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I am working on a CentOS 7 virtual server with Vagrant 1.6.5.
I have a shell "bootstrap.sh", where I want to make a symbolic link
for PhpMyAdmin like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I noticed there were problems with symbolic links with Virtual Box.
I am using Virtual Box version 4.3.16. So I placed this in my Vagrantfile:

```rb
config.vm.box = "centos"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 vb.name = "centos"
 #Enable symbolic linking
 vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/centos", "1"]
end
```

After I hit "vagrant up" and when I check
"/usr/share/nginx/html" there are none symbolic links.
When I restart the virtual CentOS machine and do the same:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I am able to make a symbolic link, but I want to do that when I typ
"vagrant up" offcourse. I also tried installing the vbguest plugin (without config) from:
https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest

How can I make it work when I typ "vagrant up"?

Comment: Can you include your whole Vagrantfile and bootstrap.sh? Or, at least the portions relevant to the symbolic link setting.

Comment: @BrianC My project is on Github, if you want to check all the code:
https://github.com/JeroenSteen/Vagrant_CentOS7/tree/master/vagrant

Comment: I played with it a bit, but could not come up with a working solution. I have not done much with symlinks inside of Vagrant unfortunately.